# In Python, how do I get the list of classes defined within a particular file?

Tags: python, inspection

If a file `myfile.py` contains:

```
class A(object):
  # Some implementation

class B (object):
  # Some implementation
```

How can I define a method so that, given `myfile.py`, it returns
[A, B]?

Here, the returned values for A and B can be either the name of the classes or the type of the classes.

`(i.e. type(A) = type(str) or type(A) = type(type))`

Comment: `dir(my file)`?

Comment: What are you intending to do with those classes? Does it matter that they are *classes* or is any *callable* sufficient? Do you want all the names in the module that name classes, or just the classes that were *defined* within that file?

Comment: @DanielPryden: I want to eventually create instances of those types dynamically. So, I would prefer classes to callables. I prefer not to have all the names in the module. Rather, I would like only those classes defined in the file or a way to easilly screen all members to return only hose classes defined in the file.

Comment: @EricMcLachlan: I suspect you would be better served by something like a class decorator that registers classes that can be dynamically instantiated with a central registry. Basically: you probably want this to be opt-in rather than a heuristic that opts some classes out.

Comment: Also: you probably don't want to discover all classes in a module, since there is nothing meaningful you can do with a class object if you don't know anything about it *a priori* -- you can't even construct an instance unless you know the correct constructor arguments to provide. And if your ultimate goal is to provide a way for clients to construct arbitrary objects you have a gaping security hole which will be impossible to completely close with a blacklisting approach: you will *need* to use whitelisting to be secure.

Comment: @DanielPryden: No doubt you are right that a decorator would work better. As someone recently said to me, "Python isn't my first language". :P
I've added my use-case below. It works. That's good enough for me for now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can get both:

```
import importlib, inspect
for name, cls in inspect.getmembers(importlib.import_module("myfile"), inspect.isclass):
```

you may additionally want to check:

```
if cls.__module__ == 'myfile'
```

Comment: Yep, that did it for me. And yep, I needed that additional check. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In case it helps someone else. Here is the final solution that I used. This method returns all classes defined in a particular package.

I keep all of the subclasses of X in a particular folder (package) and then, using this method, I can load all the subclasses of X, even if they haven't been imported yet. (If they haven't been imported yet, they cannot be accessible via `__all__`; otherwise things would have been much easier).

```
import importlib, os, inspect

def get_modules_in_package(package_name: str):
    files = os.listdir(package_name)
    for file in files:
        if file not in ['__init__.py', '__pycache__']:
            if file[-3:] != '.py':
                continue

            file_name = file[:-3]
            module_name = package_name + '.' + file_name
            for name, cls in inspect.getmembers(importlib.import_module(module_name), inspect.isclass):
                if cls.__module__ == module_name:
                    yield cls
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit long-winded, but you first need to load the file as a module, then inspect its methods to see which are classes:

```
import inspect
import importlib.util

# Load the module from file
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("foo", "foo.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)

# Return a list of all attributes of foo which are classes
[x for x in dir(foo) if inspect.isclass(getattr(foo, x))]
```

Comment: Note that if you `import` a class from another module, it will show up in the result here, even though it wasn't declared within this module. For example, if you have `from datetime import timedelta` at the top of the module, `timedelta` will show up as an attribute of the module object and `inspect.isclass` will correctly identify it was a class.

Comment: Nothing at all wrong with this answer. I just happened to get the other solution working first. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Just building on the answers above.

If you need a list of the classes defined within the module (file), i.e. not just those present in the module namespace, and you want the list *within that module*, i.e. using reflection, then the below will work under both `__name__ == __main__` and `__name__ == <module>` cases.

```
import sys, inspect

# You can pass a lambda function as the predicate for getmembers()
[name, cls in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], lambda x: inspect.isclass(x) and (x.__module__ == __name__))]
```

In my very specific use case of registering classes to a calling framework, I used as follows:

```
def register():    
    myLogger.info(f'Registering classes defined in module {__name__}')
    for name, cls in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], lambda x: inspect.isclass(x) and (x.__module__ == __name__)):
        myLogger.debug(f'Registering class {cls} with name {name}')
        <framework>.register_class(cls)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case importing the file throws errors or is not desirable, one could use the following:

```
import pyclbr
[k for k, v in pyclbr.readmodule('myfile.py').items() if isinstance(v, pyclbr.Class)]
```